# Jacobi method for compressed sparse row

Tags: compression, sparse-matrix

I'm trying the algorithm from a research paper which is used for compressed sparse row format to perform Jacobi iteration. I'm trying the example given in the research paper. I'm using Python and I'm running into errors. Please help. Thank you for your time and consideration.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse import diags
from numpy import linalg as LA
np_1=np.array([[3,0,0,1],[1,4,0,2]])
np_2=np.array([[0,0,2,0],[2,0,3,6]])
np.append(np_1, np_2, axis=0)
A=np.append(np_1, np_2, axis=0)
ACSR=sparse.csr_matrix(A)
ACSR.indptr
IA=ACSR.indptr
jA=ACSR.indices
x=np.array([0,0,0,0])
N=20
n=len(A)
b=np.array([6,-2,6,13])


for p in range(20):
    for i in range(n):
        t=b[i]
        for j in range(IA[i],IA[i+1]-1):
            if j==i:
                D=A[j]
                print(D)
            else:
                t=t-A[j]*x[jA[j]]
            print(t)
        
        x[i]=t/D
    print(x)
endfor
```

Above is the coding i tried in Python.
[Image given below is the algorithm given in the research paper]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyunM.png)

[Below is the example given in the research paper.How can i get the output given in the research paper?]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VatAP.png)

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: The images are hard to read - too small and out of focus when zoomed.  We can help with python errors, but making sure that your code and results match the paper's is outside of our (at least mine) scope of interest.

Comment: Hi...how can i contact you? Is there any email?

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code and go this output:

```
[3 0 0 1]
6
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6836\3967110093.py:29: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  x[i]=t/D
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[103], line 29
     26                 t=t-A[j]*x[jA[j]]
     27             print(t)
---> 29         x[i]=t/D
     30     print(x)
     31 endfor

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Since I ran this in an interactive ipython session I can check values, as they were left due to the error:

```
In [104]: x
Out[104]: array([0, 0, 0, 0])    # 1d array as expect by the creation line

In [105]: i           # x[i] is a slot for ONE value
Out[105]: 0
In [106]: x[i]
Out[106]: 0
```

What are you trying to assign to that slot:

```
In [107]: t
Out[107]: 6    
In [109]: D
Out[109]: array([3, 0, 0, 1])    # 4 element array

In [110]: t/D
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6836\1390120621.py:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  t/D
Out[110]: array([ 2., inf, inf,  6.])
```

That explains the Warning.  And the error - A 4 element array/sequence cannot be put into a 1 element slot.

Oops, I see you already printed the `t` and `D` values.  There for you should have already been aware of the source of this problem.

`D` is a `A[j]`, a 1d row extracted from the 2d `A`.

I don't know what you intended to happen here, but what I'm seeing a clear lack of debugging skills.  When you get errors - SHOW THEM.  And throw up your hands in dispair, running to the internet for help. :)  Identify the problem, and then you can decide on a correction.

I still can't read the images, but I suspect part of the problem is that you are selecting wholes rows of the `A` array, rather the successive nonzero elements of `A` (or `ACSR`).  So let's get those elements:

```
In [160]: dA =ACSR.data
In [161]: dA
Out[161]: array([3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 6], dtype=int32)
```

And change the loop to step through those (I removed a -1).  Now the assignment to `x[i]` works fine (it's scalar):

```
In [162]: x = np.zeros(4, float)
     ...: for i in range(4):
     ...:     t=b[i]
     ...:     for j in range(IA[i],IA[i+1]):
     ...:         print('j',j, dA[j])
     ...:         if j==i:
     ...:             D=dA[j]
     ...:         else:
     ...:             t=t-dA[j]*x[jA[j]]
     ...:     x[i] = t/D
     ...:     
j 0 3     # i=0
j 1 1
j 2 1     # i=1
j 3 4
j 4 2
j 5 2     # i=2
j 6 2     # i=3
j 7 3
j 8 6

In [163]: x
Out[163]: array([ 2.        , -1.33333333,  2.        ,  1.        ])
```

Your initialed `x` as `[0,0,0,0]`, int dtype; I let it be float, since `t/D` might be fractional.

This might not be right, but at least it runs without an obvious error.