# compressed sparse row and Jacobi iterative method

Tags: sparse-matrix

I've tried implementing Jacobi method for compressed sparse row format. But i couldnt obtain the output correctly. Below is the coding i tried. I'm trying with a 4 by 4 sparse matrix which is a tridiagonal matrix stored in compressed form before implementing Jacobi iterative method. Please help.

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;



H=4;
a=2;
b=-1;
c=-1;
A = diag(a*ones(1,H)) + diag(b*ones(1,H-1),1) + diag(c*ones(1,H-1),-1);%Matrix A
n = size(A,1); % no of rows
m = size(A,2); % no of columns



V = [];
C = [];
R = [];


counter=1;
R= [counter];
for i=1:n
  for j=1:m
    if (A(i,j) ~= 0)
      V = [V A(i,j)];
      C = [C j];
      counter=counter+1;
    end
    R(i+1)=counter;
  end
end





b = [9,18,24,3];
x_new = [1 ; 1 ; 1 ; 1];

eps = 1e-5;  % 1 x 10^(-10).
error = 1000; % use any large value greater than eps to make sure that the loop can work

counter2=1;
while (error > eps)

  x_old = x_new;

  for i=1:length(R)-1  %modified
    t = 0;
    for j=R(i):R(i+1)-1 %modified
      if (C(j)~=i)   %not equal
   
        t = t + x_old(C(j))*A(i,C(j)); %modified
      end
    end
    x_new(i,1) = (b(i) - t)/A(i,C(j)); % is a row vector
  end
  error = norm(x_new-x_old);
  counter2=counter2+1;
  end

x_new % print x



Expected output is 
[28.1987   47.3978   48.5979   25.7986]
```

this is the coding i tried and the expected output is above. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jacobi method for compressed sparse row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74935938/jacobi-method-for-compressed-sparse-row)

Comment: This looks like MATLAB code, but there's not tag for that.  Your previous question used python (though again without the language tag).  Did you learn anything from that answer?